# Integrating PunBB login system with the rest of my site

Tags: punbb

First off, I am presuming this is possible please correct me if I am wrong.
I have a simple login / registration system on my site now, however decided to delete this when installing PunBB discussion board. I prefer PunBB's login to my own so I was wondering whether it is possible to make login to the site only achievable through PunBB. Is their an extension for this? Or do you know of any useful sources that will help me implement this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Undoubtedly, PunBB uses some kind of cookie or hash to determine if a user is logged in or not. Simply use that cookie or hash in your own pages to determine who is logged in when you're not on a PunBB page.

There's probably an include file you can use for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this page](http://punbb.informer.com/docs/dev.html#integration) for information on implementing PunBB functionality into other parts of your website and details of the database schema.

Comment: Using that code, but all I am getting when opening the site is "The constant FORUM_ROOT must be defined and point to a valid PunBB installation root directory."